# grails 3.0.3 caching does not work

Tags: grails, caching

I created new grails 3.0.3 application like:
grails create-app cache_test

Added one single controller into there with one method:

```
package cache_test

import grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager

class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    CacheManager grailsCacheManager

    @Cacheable(value = "index")
    def index() {
        System.err.println("Invoked")
        render("Hello man")
    }}
```

And I expect that index() method result will be in the cache after the first invocation, however, this method is invoking each time I send request.

What did I wrong?

Comment: However, if I do the same caching in service - it does work. So I can't understand the difference - why it's working in services but not working in controllers?

Comment: I've posted also a defect on grails github
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9193

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a regression of grails cache plugin.

I had to write my own interceptor for controllers which basically caches the response by request's URLs.

Ugly, buggy but works
https://github.com/vkorobkov/grails-3-caching-workaround/